# prime number generator in mysql using repeat loop

Tags: mysql, sql

The task is to print prime no in special format. I have written a MySQL script but it is throwing error.

```
noGeneratorLoop:REPEAT

        SET isFactor=1;
        SET noOfFactors=0;
                factorsCheckLoop:REPEAT
                    IF i%isFactor=0 THEN
                        SET noOfFactors = noOfFactors+1;
                    END IF;
    
                SET isFactor=isFactor+1;
                UNTIL isFactor<=i
                END REPEAT factorsCheckLoop;
    
        IF noOfFactors=2 THEN
        SET Message=CONCAT(MESSAGE," | ",isFactor);
        END IF;
    
        SET i = i+1;
        UNTIL i<100    
    END REPEAT noGeneratorLoop;
```

This is the nested loop.And all required declaration are done ( i=1 ).I think the main problem is the line `UNTIL isFactor<=i` when I am writing some integer constant in place of `i` it is running fine.
The error name is lost connection with MySQL during query. So what is the reason for this and how to remove the error.

Comment: @Akina As you said I am incrementing `isFactor` and i is constant. So what is the problem with `isFactor<=i` as it checks whether `i` is greater than `isFactor` or not.And I am incrementing `isFactor` so the nested `REPEAT` needs to be terminate.Please elaborate if I am not getting what you wanna say.

Comment: Maybe it's better to create new question with the task? like "I need a generator which will generate values list according to the starting values ... and with the rules: ...".

Comment: Note that an RDBMS is for the storage and retrieval of relational, and not much else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hUuEgtvFscwLfh4CnMQgAG/0)

- Variables definitions/initializations added.
- Debugging statements added.
- Anti-infinite loop check added.

If initial value for `i` variable is below 2 (0 and 1 in the fiddle) then infinite loop observed.

Investigate...